# Which ばっか is used in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, particle-ばかり

I'm having trouble interpreting the following passage. None of the definition of ばかり seems to fit. Can someone help me please?

> お前．．．全部C先輩のせいみたいに言うなよな。根拠もねーくせに．．．
>
> A君のそういう．．．肝心なとこばっかにぶいとこ。Bちゃん嫌いじゃねーけど
>
> いつか命取りになっても．．．しらないよ。

The ばっか is in the second line.

Answer (score 3):

This ばっか is an informal version of ばかり, and it does mean "only".

> 肝心なとこばっかにぶいとこ
>   = 肝心なところばかり(が/で)鈍い【にぶい】ところ
>   = (Your character of being) insensible only to important things (or only in important situations)

(This remark is often used to describe a male character in a certain type of light-novel/manga, where he is surprisingly unaware of the fact that he is liked by surrounding girls.)